# NetTrain with OpenCL

Tags: machine-learning, gpu

When working with NetTrain I get the following error:

> TargetDevice -> {GPU,0} could not be used, please ensure that you have
>   a compatible graphics card and have installed CUDA drivers.

Is it possible to configure NetTrain to work with OpenCL?

Comment: No, not at this moment.